# jQuery get wrapper does not trigger fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote a small wrapper for all jQuery ajax requests so that I can queue them. My issue is that once I send the request into my queue, the initiator lost the ability to then listen to the responses (done/fail/always).

To resolve this I wrote a wrapper to use like a static class

```
function AjaxRequest(){
   this.queue = null;
}
AjaxRequest.queue = new MyQueue();

AjaxRequest.get = function(file){
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  var data = null;

  var ajax = function(){
    return $.get(file)
       .done(function(data){
          defer.resolve(data);
       })
       .fail(function(){
         defer.fail();
     });
  } 

  this.queue.enqueue(ajax);
  return defer.promise(data);
}
```

The .done() and .always() trigger, but I don't get any errors when I should fail (via bad data). I do get these errors if I unwrap and use native jQuery .get(), so I am doing something wrong in the wrapper. I am not returning .fail() properly.

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. You do not need to have a queue managing your requests, let the browser do it as different browsers let different amount of requests occur concurrently. By having your own queueing system you are removing the browsers ability to optimize your requests.

Comment: Err no, I was surpassing the limit of 6 concurrent connections in my app. I need a queue and it works beautifully.

Comment: The browser has built in queuing.  It will automatically queue up your items for you, now if you have implemented a weighted queue ; i.e you  queue has a way of moving items internally if a higher priority item comes in then cool. With the understanding that any browser update will force you to re-evaluate your queue, to make sure it takes full advantage of the new browser features.If you queue inst weighted then you should let the browser do it for you. Either way this micro-optimization is a bad call, and you should just let the browser do it for you

Comment: I don't have a weighted queue. I work on embedded systems with web servers. They can be very slow when the system is busy. It is very easy to have requests take seconds, and just as easy for them to start piling up and failing, especially when the come in bursts. Wiresharking revealed that the Browser was disconnecting my requests. My queue has eradicated this issue.

Comment: I retract my statements, for your situation a queue is the solution

Comment: What's the purpose of the `data` argument to `defer.promise()`? Does it help to leave this out?